# why a non-dba user can log in as sysdba?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

in my oracle instance, I have a user called `xxx`, I remembered I just grant `resource` and `connect` role to `xxx`, but now the user can log in as `sysdba`(via pl/sql developer), even after executing `revoke dba from xxx` through `sys` account, the user `xxx` can still log in as `sysdba`, so why? What should I do to revoke his `dba` role?

*PS*: now I execute `revoke dba from xxx`, it reports an error: dba role is not granted to xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `DBA` role and `SYSDBA` roles are different.

```
revoke sysdba from xxx;
```

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dba006.htm#i1006554) about Administrative Privileges

Comment: are connecting from the server with an OS user with super user privileges ?

Comment: `xxx` is not an OS user, it is created by `sys` account. Just now I recreate a new account, this sql is below:                         `create user nader2 identified by nader;
    grant connect to nader2;
    grant resource to nader2;`                                          now `nader2` can also log in as `sysdba`.

Comment: i'm asking about the OS user because you seem to create the user ok. but, if you log from the database server with a super user - the OS grants him the privilege to connect as sysdba. you understand ?

Comment: @hiway - I think @haki is right; connections using `SYSDBA` as handled differently, as described in the linked document. You may notice that it doesn't matter if you get the user ID/password wrong, and that `select user from dual` shows `SYS` rather than `XXX`.

Comment: @haki, sorry for my poor understanding, can I avoid the OS authentication, that is to say, not permit `xxx` to log as `sysdba`?

Comment: i don't know. try to see if you can run sqlplus as a different os user.